# Change text color of inner html value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this piece of code which is inside of a foreach that prints out the status of a ticket. It has 3 different status values of Open, Closed and Overdue.

I want to change the colour of each text value as it is printed to the view either by way of adding a class dynamically into the element tag

```
Overdue -> Red

Open -> Green

Closed -> Blue
```

EG: The values are wrapped in a `<td><span class="status"> Overdue </span></td>`

The html/php code:

```
<table id="responsive-datatables" class="table hidden table-bordered table-striped table-hover dt-responsive non-responsive dataTable no-footer dtr-inline">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="per5">#</th>
            <th class="per20">Title</th>
            <th class="per20 hidden-xs hidden-sm">Creator</th>
            <th class="per20 hidden-xs hidden-sm">Assignee</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Priority</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Status</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $tickets) { ?>
            <tr <?=status_class(element('status', $tickets))?>>
                <td><a href="<?=site_url('tickets/profile/id/' . element('ticket_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('ticket_id', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('tickets/profile/id/' . element('ticket_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('title', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('user/profile/id/' . element('created_user_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('created_user', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('user/profile/id/' . element('assigned_user_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('assigned_user', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span><?=html_escape(element('priority', $tickets))?></span></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span class="status"><?=html_escape(element('status', $tickets))?></span></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span><?=html_escape(element('created', $tickets))?></span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The jQuery to add class to element:

```
if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Overdue")) {
    $(".status").addClass("red");
} else if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Closed")) {
    $(".status").addClass("lightblue");
} else if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Open")) {
    $(".status").addClass("green");
}
```

Currently it is only adding the .red class for "**Overdue**" status.
Is it possible to use an array to find all the span elements and loop through them and apply the necessary class needed for each ticket status?

Comment: why dont you use the php conditions to print the class name wen you have foreach loop  ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try with** **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** .Then add the class of matched text

```js
if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Overdue")) {
    $(".status").addClass("red");
} else if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Closed")) {
    $(".status").addClass("lightblue");
} else if ($("td span").hasClass("status") && $("td span").html("Open")) {
    $(".status").addClass("green");
}

$('span:contains("Overdue")').addClass('red');
$('span:contains("Open")').addClass('green');
$('span:contains("Closed")').addClass('blue');
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green;}
.blue{color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="responsive-datatables" class="table hidden table-bordered table-striped table-hover dt-responsive non-responsive dataTable no-footer dtr-inline">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="per5">#</th>
            <th class="per20">Title</th>
            <th class="per20 hidden-xs hidden-sm">Creator</th>
            <th class="per20 hidden-xs hidden-sm">Assignee</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Priority</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Status</th>
            <th class="per10 hidden-xs">Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $tickets) { ?>
            <tr <?=status_class(element('status', $tickets))?>>
                <td><a href="<?=site_url('tickets/profile/id/' . element('ticket_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('ticket_id', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('tickets/profile/id/' . element('ticket_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('title', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('user/profile/id/' . element('created_user_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('created_user', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="<?=site_url('user/profile/id/' . element('assigned_user_id', $tickets, ''))?>"><?=html_escape(element('assigned_user', $tickets))?></a></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span><?=html_escape(element('priority', $tickets))?></span></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span class="status"><?=html_escape(element('status', $tickets))?></span></td>
                <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span><?=html_escape(element('created', $tickets))?></span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the element and perform desired operation on the matched element.

```
var status = $("td span.status");
status.filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.trim() === 'Overdue'; //Exact match
}).addClass("red");
status.filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.trim() === 'Open'; //Exact match
}).addClass("green");
status.filter(function(){
    return this.textContent.trim() === 'Closed'; //Exact match
}).addClass("blue");
```

You can also use [`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), However it will not result in exact match

```
var status = $("td span.status");
status.filter(":contains('Overdue')").addClass("red");
status.filter(":contains('Open')").addClass("green");
status.filter(":contains('Closed')").addClass("blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the following things:

- If you use `hasClass` on `$("tr td span")` it will return only the evaluation for one of the elements matching the `tr td span` selector. You don't loop through each of them. If you want to loop through them all you should use a function such as `each` or `map` on the result of `$("tr td span")`, and then check for the conditions to be met.
- also, you try to check is the span object has a specific text inside, but by `$("td span").html("Overdue")` you are actually inserting the text in the DOM object, not evaluating its presence inside that object.

```js
$("td span").each(function(idx, obj) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('status') && $(this).html().toLowerCase() == 'overdue') $(this).addClass('red');
  if ($(this).hasClass('status') && $(this).html().toLowerCase() == 'closed') $(this).addClass('blue');
  if ($(this).hasClass('status') && $(this).html().toLowerCase() == 'open') $(this).addClass('green');
});
```

```css
tr td { background:#ACACAC; font-weight:bold;}
.red {color:red;}
.green {color:green}
.blue {color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="status">Overdue</span></td>
    <td><span>Overdue (but no status class)</span></td>
    <td><span class="status">Open</span></td>
    <td><span class="status">Closed</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, the code could be simplified by using CSS selectors with jQuery instead of evaluating JS conditions.

Thus, also avoiding the need for a loop.

```js
$("td span.status:contains(Overdue)").addClass('red');
$("td span.status:contains(Open)").addClass('green');
$("td span.status:contains(Close)").addClass('blue');
```

```css
tr td { background:#ACACAC; font-weight:bold;}
.red {color:red;}
.green {color:green}
.blue {color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="status">Overdue</span></td>
    <td><span>Overdue (but no status class)</span></td>
    <td><span class="status">Open</span></td>
    <td><span class="status">Closed</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. As I was attempting my solution it did not seem right as it was adding the text value in the .html("Overdue") to the view but also in other columns which I am not trying to target with the addClass();